# Sharing data from an API between components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a website that shows the top 20 rated Sci-fi movies. The homepage component uses a GET request via a service to get an array of objects containing the movies` data. This movie data is rendered using `ngFor*` in its HTML template.

Each movie thumbnail has a click handler that routes to a different page that will display more information about that selected movie - i.e. description, ratings etc. For this second page, I am using a service that makes another GET request, where the query contains the selected movie's id as a parameter.

Homepage component that renders initial API movie data:

```
`
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieDataService } from '../services/movie-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-card',
  templateUrl: './home-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-card.component.css']
})
export class HomeCardComponent {

  movieData: any = {};
  constructor(private movieDataService: MovieDataService) {}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movieDataService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.movieData = data;
      // JSON to console
      console.warn(data);
    })
  }
}
`
```

HTML for the homepage:

```
`
<div class="wrapper-grid">
    <div *ngFor="let result of movieData.results;" class="container">
      <img routerLink="/movieInfo" src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780{{result.poster_path}}'   alt='thumbnail' class="thumbnail-img">
      <info-page [movieId]="result.id"></info-page>
      <p class="home-text">{{result.title}}</p>
      <p class="home-date">{{result.release_date}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
`
```

Single movie page that will render the selected movie's data

```
`
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { single } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'info-page',
  templateUrl: './info-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info-page.component.css']
})
export class InfoPageComponent {

  @Input()
  movieId: number;

  singleMovieData: any = {} ;

  constructor(private DataService: DataService) {}

  getMovie() {
    this.DataService.getMovie(this.movieId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.singleMovieData = data;
      // console.warn(data);
      // console.log(this.movieId)
      // console.log(this.singleMovieData.id)
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMovie()
  }

}
`
```

Service for the Single Movie page

```
`
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  movieId: number;

  public getMovie(movieId: number) {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?  api_key=9279f87c4b7f1cb1474b6d7cd6958a6d&language=en-US`);
  }

}
`
```

As of now, each function is working correctly - when logging movieId & singleMovieData I am getting the correct information I'm looking for.

But when the GET request in the service for the Single Movie Page is executed, I get a 404 saying that the parameter for `movieId` is undefined. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The movieId property in the DataService is not being set to the value passed in as an argument in the getMovie() method. Therefore the API URL being used to make the GET request has an undefined movie ID parameter resulting in the 404.

You should remove the movieId property from the DataService class and instead pass the movieId parameter directly to the get() method in the getMovie() method. The movieId parameter passed to the getMovie() method will be used in the API URL to make the GET request. This should solve the 404 error:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getMovie(movieId: number) {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movieId}?api_key=9279f87c4b7f1cb1474b6d7cd6958a6d&language=en-US`);
  }

}
```